# Why does the Java Math library not have functions that return floating point?

Tags: java, math, double

For instance, in the following snippet:

```
float roll = (float)Math.atan2(sinr, cosr);
```

Math.atan2 returns a double, so I cast it to a float. However, most functions I've used are returning of type double, which makes it sort of tedious that I have to cast so frequently, which made me think I'm using the library wrong. I need my data in type float to work with other classes that also utilize floats.

I'm wondering why there aren't multiple versions of the Math functions to cast doubles to floats, which allow floats to be returned instead of doubles (if needed). I understand why the math shouldn't be directly in floating point, but the library seems inflexible to programmers who are working exclusively with floating point.

**Why does the library mostly return of type double?**

Comment: Just write a trivial class that delegates to `java.lang.Math`, and does the casting in one place. Or, do the same thing for the classes which require things to be floats.

Comment: For Android, [yes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/FloatMath) (although it's deprecated, and it's apparently slower). For SE, nope.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do floating point math using `float`? It has a horrendously low precision, as low as [6 significant decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32).

Comment: @Andreas A lot of gaming libraries use `float` opposed to `double`. However, most of these gaming libraries provide an API for required math functions.

Comment: You are not using the wrong library. What you are doing wrong is using floats.You should really never use floats - they give at best about 8 [place accuracy. Try adding 1/100.0  to one million and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. I don't necessarily want a library that does "math using floating point", I just wish there were functions that returned floats. For instance there could be something like Math.cosF() that just does the casting for you.

Comment: IMO, your question can be translated as: "When I should preserve space (memory) instead of precision"? Well, if your goal is to construct the bridge (in the real world), trust me, you should use not float, not double, but BigDecimal...

Comment: @FredK There exist (many, many, many) applications which don't require extreme accuracy. What if he was running a 32 bit machine & would prefer to avoid atomic read/writes when using a 64 bit double?

Comment: It's too bad this questions is already closed. This is a meaningful, interesting question. The reason is that it's pretty hard to get a math library correct; having just one set of functions (double) considerably reduces the work. One can get single-precision values by just truncating the results. This is a trade-off -- it is slightly less efficient at run time, but simplifies the implementation a lot. Decades ago, there were commonly two versions of all math functions, single and double, so that programmers could choose for themselves. That Java had just one set was a break with tradition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a third-party library:

```
class FloatMath {
  float atan2(float y, float x) {
    return (float) Math.atan2(y, x);
  }

  // etc, for other methods.
}
```

You can write delegating methods like this only for the methods you require. Then just call this in place of `java.lang.Math`.

However, you should strongly consider doing this the other way round: use `java.lang.Math` directly, and wrap the library call which require things to be `float` behind a similar facade.